# Find coordinate on image client sided

Tags: javascript, image

I've got a png `800x800`. After clicking on a certain position(pixel) on the image, let's say `200x300` I want to save these coordinates.

What would be an approach to get these coordinates relative to the image when clicking it?

I don't expect you to just give me the code, reference would be also good.

Comment: PHP will not be a tool available to you, PHP is server side.

Comment: @chris85: So how do you save data with only a client side programming language? It is possible, but probably not what 0x45 wants.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The question is not about saving. `What would be an approach to get these coordinates relative to the image when clicking it?`

Comment: @chris85: Yes, that is true. However the question also mentions: `I want to save these coordinates.`, as you might have read, and *Don't Panic* also did (past tense!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually an `<input type="image">` html element does exactly what you need.

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  <input type="image" src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/avatar_c5ab8cc59f62_128.png" alt="Submit" width="128" height="128">
</form>
```

When clicked, submits the form and returns coordinates of the click within the image in **x** & **y** variables (POST or GET, depending on the form's method attribute).

demo : https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_height_width

Comment: I like it, very simple. :-) One disadvantage is the 'submit' part, but you can work around that.

Comment: Okay, awesome. It's so straight forward that even a beginner like me will get it!
Thank and this is somehow exactly what I needed since I save these as `$_GET` or `$_POST`!
AWESOME!

Comment: Glad to help, and glad I could offer it as an answer as well. It's an old, forgotten html feature that deserves to be better known :-)

Answer (score 4):

You have to start with an image

```
<img id="something" src="some_image.png">
```

Then you'd need an event handler

```
document.getElementById('something').addEventListener('click', fn);
```

Then you'd need the `fn` function you're calling in the event handler

```
function fn(event) { ... }
```

Inside that event handler, you can now get the coordinates from the event object

```
function fn(event) {
     var x = event.clientX;
     var y = event.clientY;
}
```

`clientX` and `clientY` will give you the coordinates relative to the element you're clicking, in this case the image, where the upper left corner is `0, 0`

If you wanted to save that, you could use `localStorage`

```
function fn(event) {
     var x = event.clientX;
     var y = event.clientY;

     localStorage.setItem('coords', '{"x":"'+x+'", "y":"'+y+'"}');
}
```

and when you want to get it back, it's

```
var coords = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('coords') )
```

Comment: On your `fn(event)`, please do not build JSON manually. Use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) instead.

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer!
So how would I save these to a lets say a php variable?

Comment: @0x45 Please do some research effort and, if necessary, elaborate another question on that matter.

Comment: @DineiRockenbach - I'm so good, I even stringify JSON on the fly! Creating JSON like that isn't an issue, unless you don't know what you're doing, then you should stick to using `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @adeneo Me too, sometimes. But IMHO as we're answering questions for people with [generally] less knowledge it's better to stick with the best approach for general use cases.

Answer (score 4):

you can simply use mouse click event :

```
function Coords(event) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var coords = "X : " + x + ", Y : " + y;
    document.getElementById("coords").innerHTML = coords;
}
```

DEMO:http://jsbin.com/hucoliyane/1/edit?html,js,output

:)

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery we can get the clicked position. The corresponding code snippet is here below with the demo.

```js
$("#imageId").click(function(e){
   var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
   //or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
   var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
   var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
   console.log("X : "+relX);
   console.log("Y : "+relY);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="imageId" alt="image" src="http://www.builtinchicago.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/opengraph/company_logos/some_logo_blue_2_1_copy.png">
```

Comment: Is this is the expected output that you need?

Comment: It's doing the job, but for a beginner like me proably too hard, still upvote.
Thanks for your help.